# Он — гребец, она — ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если он пловец, то она — пловчиха. А как насчет "гребца"? Есть ведь девушки, занимающиеся греблей. А как их назвать одним словом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Гребчиха, борчиха*** и многие другие давно и безальтернативно используется спортивными комментаторами.
Полагаю, можно ожидать и признания полной нормативности. Во всяком случае Лопатин уже включил в словарь.

Answer (score 3):

**Девушка-гребец**, можно и *гребчиха*. Очень многие виды занятий, изначально связанные только с представителями одного пола, не имеют слов для обозначения представителя другого пола в той же профессии. Чаще всего эти занятия мужские (борец, грузчик), но бывают и женские (швея, прачка)

Answer (score 0):

```
Меня (гребчиха) коробит.
```

Comment: Fora, старайтесь давать  более развернутые ответы. То, что кого-то коробит - еще не аргумент.